# Is there an equivalent to CSS for XIB (XCode Interface Builder XML)?

Tags: css, themes, xib, skin

Is there any way to apply a style XIB files created by XCode? Something equivalent to styling an HTML file with CSS? I'd like to be able to, say, change the background image for all buttons or for all buttons of a certain class.

(I realize I could probably use XSLT to transform the XIB file or subclass NSButton to set a default background but I'd much rather use a stylesheet type mechanism if one exists)

Thanks,
-- James

Comment: I am not aware of any css like technology but you could write a category for your buttons which incorporates a method `[UIButton buttonWithDefaultBackground:bgImage]`.

Comment: You can now use IBInspectable and IBDesignable to define all your styles in one particular place, and then have Interface Builder pull from that code automatically (without having to run the simulator). Here's a step-by-step guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682764/accessing-text-styles-in-interface-builder-and-or-storyboards. That example is for font size and UILabels, but it should work for other views and properties too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for something similar. I found this which are the closest I could find:

**Inspectable**:

Ability to add more personalization features to the interface, like round corners, border width, border color... 
https://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

Afterwards, I created this for buttons as an example:

```
@IBDesignable public class DesignableButton: UIButton {        
    @IBInspectable var buttonStyle: String {
        set {
            switch newValue  {
            case "green":
                layer.frame.size.height = 44
                layer.cornerRadius = 22
                layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
            case "white":
                layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                layer.frame.size.height = 44
                layer.cornerRadius = 22
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift UI**:

Haven't tried but seems like a great solution, you can stylize your app using CSS: 
https://github.com/tombenner/nui

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, no such mechanism exists. It depends on your needs, but what you might be able to do is use a WebView for your application's UI; this would allow full CSS customization.

An example can be found on [Matt Gemmel's blog](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/24/skinnable-cocoa-ui-with-webkit-and-css/). [CocUI](https://github.com/rsms/cocui) may also be of interest.

Comment: Using webview will decrease considerably the user experience